# Will signing my code with a code signing cert allow my app to run in normal permissions mode?

Tags: certificate, signing

I have an application that needs to run in normal (non elevated) permissions to allow drag and drop from windows explerer with the UAC on in Vista, Win7 and Win8.   Can anyone please tell me if signing my code with a code signing certificate and including a manifest allow my app to run without requiring the user to turn off UAC to accept drag and drop?   I would like to get some input before I invest in a pricy code signing cert.   Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Signing has _nothing_ to do with admin.  Either you need admin or you don't; you can't change that by signing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Code signing alone will not change that. It will identify you as the author (reading "Publisher: Company Name" instead of "Publisher: Unknown" on the UAC popup), but does not solve your permissions problem.